# Why simple column multiplication not working in Python 3.5, Pandas 0.23?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to create a computed column with a monthly value from an hourly value.

I tried this

`df['Monthly'] = df['SpotPrice'].multiply(744)`

this

`df['Monthly'] = df['SpotPrice'].multiply(744, level=1)`

this

`df['Monthly'] = df['SpotPrice'] * 744`

and a few other nonsensical variations that I copy/pasted from other SO answers to questions that surely this is going to be marked as a duplicate of, but nothing works.

I have:

```
Python 3.5.0 (v3.5.0:374f501f4567, Sep 13 2015, 02:27:37) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
..
>>> pandas.__version__
'0.23.0'
```

*UPDATED*

My existing DataFrame looks like this

```
    AvailabilityZone InstanceType ProductDescription SpotPrice                 Timestamp
40        us-east-2b     t2.micro         Linux/UNIX  0.003500 2018-07-07 22:09:52+00:00
940       us-east-2c     t2.micro         Linux/UNIX  0.003500 2018-07-06 22:09:47+00:00
941       us-east-2b     t2.micro         Linux/UNIX  0.003500 2018-07-06 22:09:47+00:00
942       us-east-2a     t2.micro         Linux/UNIX  0.003500 2018-07-06 22:09:47+00:00
39        us-east-2c     t2.micro         Linux/UNIX  0.003500 2018-07-07 22:09:52+00:00
41        us-east-2a     t2.micro         Linux/UNIX  0.003500 2018-07-07 22:09:52+00:00
115       us-east-2a     t2.small         Linux/UNIX  0.006900 2018-07-07 21:25:10+00:00
114       us-east-2b     t2.small         Linux/UNIX  0.006900 2018-07-07 21:25:10+00:00
113       us-east-2c     t2.small         Linux/UNIX  0.006900 2018-07-07 21:25:10+00:00
945       us-east-2a     t2.micro            Windows  0.008100 2018-07-06 22:09:38+00:00
44        us-east-2a     t2.micro            Windows  0.008100 2018-07-07 22:09:39+00:00
43        us-east-2b     t2.micro            Windows  0.008100 2018-07-07 22:09:39+00:00
42        us-east-2c     t2.micro            Windows  0.008100 2018-07-07 22:09:39+00:00
944       us-east-2b     t2.micro            Windows  0.008100 2018-07-06 22:09:38+00:00
943       us-east-2c     t2.micro            Windows  0.008100 2018-07-06 22:09:38+00:00
877       us-east-2c    t2.medium         Linux/UNIX  0.013900 2018-07-07 00:33:17+00:00
879       us-east-2a    t2.medium         Linux/UNIX  0.013900 2018-07-07 00:33:17+00:00
878       us-east-2b    t2.medium         Linux/UNIX  0.013900 2018-07-07 00:33:17+00:00
103       us-east-2a     t2.small            Windows  0.015900 2018-07-07 21:26:17+00:00
101       us-east-2c     t2.small            Windows  0.015900 2018-07-07 21:26:17+00:00
102       us-east-2b     t2.small            Windows  0.015900 2018-07-07 21:26:17+00:00
998       us-east-2b     t2.small            Windows  0.015900 2018-07-06 21:25:19+00:00
999       us-east-2a     t2.small            Windows  0.015900 2018-07-06 21:25:19+00:00
997       us-east-2c     t2.small            Windows  0.015900 2018-07-06 21:25:19+00:00
511       us-east-2c     c4.large         Linux/UNIX  0.017200 2018-07-07 11:33:18+00:00
```

The output looks generally like this:

```
    AvailabilityZone                        ...                                                                    Monthly
57        us-east-2a                        ...                          0.0035000.0035000.0035000.0035000.0035000.0035...
56        us-east-2b                        ...                          0.0035000.0035000.0035000.0035000.0035000.0035...
55        us-east-2c                        ...                          0.0035000.0035000.0035000.0035000.0035000.0035...
958       us-east-2a                        ...                          0.0035000.0035000.0035000.0035000.0035000.0035...
957       us-east-2b                        ...                          0.0035000.0035000.0035000.0035000.0035000.0035...
956       us-east-2c                        ...                          0.0035000.0035000.0035000.0035000.0035000.0035...
131       us-east-2a                        ...                          0.0069000.0069000.0069000.0069000.0069000.0069...
129       us-east-2c                        ...                          0.0069000.0069000.0069000.0069000.0069000.0069...
130       us-east-2b                        ...                          0.0069000.0069000.0069000.0069000.0069000.0069...
961       us-east-2a                        ...                          0.0081000.0081000.0081000.0081000.0081000.0081...
959       us-east-2c                        ...                          0.0081000.0081000.0081000.0081000.0081000.0081...
60        us-east-2a                        ...                          0.0081000.0081000.0081000.0081000.0081000.0081...
59        us-east-2b                        ...                          0.0081000.0081000.0081000.0081000.0081000.0081...
58        us-east-2c                        ...                          0.0081000.0081000.0081000.0081000.0081000.0081...
960       us-east-2b                        ...                          0.0081000.0081000.0081000.0081000.0081000.0081...
894       us-east-2b                        ...                          0.0139000.0139000.0139000.0139000.0139000.0139...
895       us-east-2a                        ...                          0.0139000.0139000.0139000.0139000.0139000.0139...
893       us-east-2c                        ...                          0.0139000.0139000.0139000.0139000.0139000.0139...
118       us-east-2b                        ...                          0.0159000.0159000.0159000.0159000.0159000.0159...
117       us-east-2c                        ...                          0.0159000.0159000.0159000.0159000.0159000.0159...
119       us-east-2a                        ...                          0.0159000.0159000.0159000.0159000.0159000.0159...
890       us-east-2c                        ...                          0.0172000.0172000.0172000.0172000.0172000.0172...
527       us-east-2c                        ...                          0.0172000.0172000.0172000.0172000.0172000.0172...
104       us-east-2b                        ...                          0.0177000.0177000.0177000.0177000.0177000.0177...
251       us-east-2a                        ...                          0.0178000.0178000.0178000.0178000.0178000.0178...
74        us-east-2c                        ...                          0.0178000.0178000.0178000.0178000.0178000.0178...
```

**The expected output would be a frame with a new column named 'Monthly' which would have the SpotPrice value multiplied by 744.**

*UPDATE2*
Here's my complete script

```
import sys
import boto3
import json
import pandas as pd
region = sys.argv[1]
client = boto3.client('ec2', region)
response = client.describe_spot_price_history()
df = pd.DataFrame(response['SpotPriceHistory'])
df = df.sort_values(by = 'SpotPrice')
df = df.head(50)
df['Monthly'] = df['SpotPrice'] * 744
print(df)
```

Comment: "not working" doesn't tell us much.  What do your examples do, and what did you expect them to do?

Comment: @JohnGordon just added.

Comment: @ScottBoston added input and actual vs expected output

Comment: SpotPrice is a str and not a numeric dtype.  What does df.info() return?

Comment: Yep. You need to clean your data. You should solve this when you "read" the data. **Show** us how you get your data.

Comment: Before giving a downvote to my answer, I'd suggest actually trying to clarify what you want.

Comment: @AntonvBR updated my question to include the entire script.

Comment: @RushabhMehta someone else downvoted your answer.

Comment: I just tried `df['Monthly'] = float(df['SpotPrice']) * 744` but that causes a new error, `TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>`

Comment: I guess Panda's magic conversions do not work with functions, only operators?

Comment: `df['Monthly'] = df['SpotPrice'].astype(float) * 744`

Comment: @Primusa that was it! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Answer provided in the comment by @Primusa:

`df['Monthly'] = df['SpotPrice'].astype(float) * 744`

Comment: While this will work, as Anton vBR mentioned in the comments, it's considered best practice to clean data on _import_, not on use.  If you were using this column repeatedly, it'd be annoying -- and potentially dangerous -- to have to remember to coerce on use.  (Dangerous because while `0.250.25` is likely to cause crashes, `2525` might not.)

Comment: @DSM what would that “clean on import” look like in code?